# How to setup an S3 bucket for a website where users can upload and download files in their specific folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have am working on a React project where users can upload files and generate a unique passcode, then create a folder in my S3 bucket named with this passcode. Then the user (or someone else) could access the website on another computer, type in this passcode and retrieve the files.

I don't have much experience with S3 so the settings are a bit overwhelming. How can I configure a bucket for this project? I read about something called a "signed-URL". Would that accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: S3 is for static websites only. You will need some backed for generation of the s3 signed url. You can do this with lambda functions as backed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a Pastebin with a password, except that it is multiple files under one code. It's also a bit similar to Dropbox, in the way that it can 'share' files.

I would recommend:

- Your app generates a Unique ID (**UUID**)
- Your app invites the user to upload a set of files:

  - These can be [Uploaded to Amazon S3 using presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html), which allow the files go to straight to S3. Make sure they are uploaded to a path prefixed with the UUID.
  - The app gives the user the UUID for later retrieval
- Another user goes to the app and requests files, providing the UUID
- The app then presents a list of files from that directory. When showing this list, the app creates an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for each file, allowing the user to download them directly from S3.
- You have some process that 'cleans up' files after a period of time, either based on the upload time and/or the download time

Basically, the Amazon S3 bucket is kept private and all objects are kept private. There is no configuration required on the bucket or the objects. Instead, the 'magic' comes from your application generating pre-signed URLs, which allow **time-limited access to a private object**.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this article : [How to host a website on S3 without getting lost in the sea](https://medium.com/@kyle.galbraith/how-to-host-a-website-on-s3-without-getting-lost-in-the-sea-e2b82aa6cd38)
Maybe this could be of your help for the scenario you have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to host a static website on S3, I just want to use S3 for users to store and retrieve files

Comment: Got it. Umm....You could refer to https://medium.com/@khelif96/uploading-files-from-a-react-app-to-aws-s3-the-right-way-541dd6be689 OR https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-upload-files-to-aws-s3-in-react-591e533d615e

Answer (score 0):

Please refrain from asking questions with full tutorial on stackoverflow as it is against community guidelines. We do are happy to send you in the right direction however its not right to ask for full code or tutorial...

If you really need the full app or code here....just post the wrong code, someone will definitely fix itfor you, but no free service

Comment: Nothing about my question asks about a "full tutorial"...